# Force display name to nickname wp

Tags: user-registration

I wondered if anyone has a solution for the following scenario i would like to force when a user registers Display name publicly to Nickname by default instead of first name and  last name which is what is set by default in WP.

Many thanks in advance JM

Comment: one addition to the question the objective is that when users generate posts written by field displays their nickname.

Comment: You can edit your question to include that note, but before you do, can you reword it? I don't understand what you mean by "written by field"

Comment: I think they mean they want the byline on posts to use the author's nickname.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Guys in response to further details on my answer, so basically i searched for plugin solutions in preference to adding code (i am not a developer) and found a plugin that does the job very well called change display name publicly as. Hope this feedback is relevant and helpful.

many thanks,

J

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [user_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) hook, which is fired after the user is registered, to set the name to whatever you like:

```
function fix_user_display_name($user_id) {
    $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
    $display_name = $user->user_nicename;

    wp_update_user(array(
        'ID'           => $user_id,
        'display_name' => $display_name
    )) ;
}

add_action("user_register", "fix_user_display_name", 20);[1]
```

Comment: `nicename` is not the same as the nickname.